# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n!} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n!} = 0,$$ using the definition of the limit of a sequence. For any given $\varepsilon > 0$, we must show that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $$\left| \frac{1}{n!} - 0 \right| < \varepsilon.$$

I am trying to work backwards and have formulated $n! > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ and tried working with the idea that $n^n > n!$ but I did not get anything fruitful. My book says as a hint to try $n! > n$ but I don't really know how it is useful.

Can someone please give me some insight into this problem?

Comment: Well, there's some integer greater than $\frac 1{\epsilon}$, right?

Comment: @lulu I understand your idea but if I want to show rigorous proof don't I need to show that $\exists M$ such that $n>N$ and since I am dealing with the factorial how do I rigorously write about such an integer's existence

Comment: you have $n! >n$ for $n>2$, taking reciprocal and work backward for $1/n$ (using Archimedean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ exist $N$ s.t. for every $n\geq N,\; \big\lvert\frac{1}{n!}\big\rvert < \epsilon$. As pointed out in the comments for $n>2,\;n! > n$ so taking the reciprocal
$$\frac{1}{n!}< \frac{1}{n}$$
(I omitted the absolute value as it is all positive) So what we need is
$$\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon \implies n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$
In the end $N = \big\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\big\rceil$. Hope this helps!